# Moving data from DB to static files, run time variables

Tags: java, mysql, database, playframework

I'm using playframework 1.2.4, and mysql database.

I have some tables that are in the DB, but are quite static. It is about 100-300 records of 4-7 keys.
I want to move them out of the DB.

In such cases, what would be the best place to store the information?

- A new play configuration file?
- XML of some-sort with a parser?
- JSON/YAML file with access (that id don't know it of :) ) from playframework/java?
- Java file that stores all the info in a class?

What's the best solution and what does playframework preach for in such cases?

Comment: What the problem, you are trying to solve, by moving the data out of DB ?

Comment: To cancel the usage of the DB, no need for it. It is all static data that changes only once in a while by me.

Comment: If you have no particular memory constraints, I would load the objects into a HashMap (or similar container), and then serialize the whole mass to disk using Java binary serialization.  Then deserialize this back into memory on start up. The suggestion to use Xml has the advantage that you can hand edit the data using a text editor, but it sounds like you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would group your options into the following:

1. Relational Database
2. XML or JSON (whether that's a config file or some separate document).
3. External in-memory caching such as [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) (also available from within Play).
4. Store the data as a Java data object, or use [Play's simple, non-distributed cache](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/cache), which stores the data in the Java heap.

You have two issues with which you'll need to deal here: 1.) the performance of accessing your data, and 2.) the maintainability of your dataset. We can deal with these separately.

**Performance**

You have two considerations regarding performance. The first is access/lag time, the second is the amount of data stored in memory. Regarding the access time, the database will certainly have the most lag. Numbers 2 and 3 will vary depending on your hardware and OS -- you'll need to do some testing in your particular setup to really know for sure which is going to perform best. Having to retrieve the XML/JSON file from disk would certainly be much slower than accessing it from an in-memory cache, but Operating Systems are typically pretty intelligent about keeping frequently accessed files available in memory, too. It may be that the overhead of using a caching system ends up being slower than just using a static file.

Your data will ultimately need to become a Java object in order for you to interact with it from your code. Thus, #1,2, and 3 will all require some serialization of external data into a Java object, which will take some amount of time. Accessing a Java variable (#4) will be the fastest, as it requires no extra serialization.

Regarding the amount of data stored in memory, #2 and #4 will require that you store the entire dataset in memory each time you run the code (i.e. load any of the relevant pages). This may not be a huge concern for 7 x 300 values (8kB, if they were all floats), but when you're expecting a single server to serve thousands of clients, that extra memory consumption used on every page load may actually become the bottle-neck for you application. You could alleviate this cost if you were able to store the data statically. Option #3 will only store the data in memory once, then shares that across all requests, which shouldn't be a big memory penalty. #1 will likely function like #3 (at worst), in that it will store one copy in memory globally. These methods will store one global copy of the data in memory, then only serialize the relevant code into Java objects (perhaps one row of the dataset).

Finally, note that the downside to using Play's internal, Java-based cache is that it costs you scalability. Be sure to read the details [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/cache).

**Maintenance**

The other concern is how difficult it will be for you to maintain the data. It sounds like you're opposed to an RDBMS-based solution because of maintenance and deployment concerns. Memcached would probably not offer you much over a database, as you would still need to ensure consistency of the cache across your deployment environments. At that point, you're left with options #2 and #4. In my mind, it's much easier to work with a dataset stored in XML or JSON than in Java, so I would say the benefit goes to the XML-based dataset in terms of maintainability.

**Conclusion**

So the best solution for maintenance and deployment is probably XML, the best in terms of performance would be Java-based objects. Thankfully, we can use a tool to get the best of both worlds. [PojoXML](http://code.google.com/p/pojoxml/) allows you to convert POJOs (Java objects) to XML and back. Thus, you can maintain your data in XML, then use PojoXML to convert that document to a Java object any time you make changes to your dataset. Then you get the performance benefits of keeping your static data in compiled Java code, with the maintainability of using XML. Just be sure to store the data as a statically so that you don't consume 8kB of memory for every page load.

Answer (score 3):

I would still keep it in DB. The "static" data what you call is kind of master data which hardly changes, and the best place for any data is the Database.

You would not really gain any advantage by moving this out of DB to a static file. Now you would have two places for your data - database and static file which would be more maintenance in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but:
First, I'm more afraid to lose the data in the DB than a repo-versioned file. And I mean moving away the data from DB, so no duplicates here. Also, It will allow me to set dev enviroument quickly since there is no real usage of DB.

Answer (score 1):

As your data volume is not too big and data is static, then the simplest way and, I think, the most efficient, will be transferring your data to your java project as a Hashtable instance. Initialize this table upon the application startup and use it whenever it is necessary.